# How to align left and keep a constant width in HStack?

Tags: swiftui

This is I tried, but left alignment does not work, strange.

```swift
HStack {
    Text("Host").frame(width: 200)
        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        .padding(.leading)
        .frame(width: 200, alignment: .leading)
    TextField("Enter Host", text: $api.url)
}
```

[image]

Comment: You have two frames specified — only one has alignment